# How to use double markers in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I wish to indicate that one curve is a hybrid of two other curves. I thought it would be a good idea to use the upper/lower triangles, and an overlay/superposition of the two for the hybrid. I.e.

- '^'
- 'v'
- a hexagram

*Problem:* there's no hexagram marker. And I don't manage to use any of the latex symbols (\DavidStar, \davidsstar, \largestarofdavid). How can I do so?

*Alternative strategy:*
 overlay '^' and 'v'. How?

*Alternative strategy:* use some other 3 symbols that complement one another. However, I cannot find such a set in [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html).

### Edit

In response to comments I tried this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
a = np.arange(5)
lh1, = ax.plot(a, a, 'k', marker='v',ms=30,markerfacecolor='none',markeredgewidth=1.5)
lh2, = ax.plot(a, a, 'k', marker='^',ms=30,markerfacecolor='none',markeredgewidth=1.5)
ax.legend([lh1,lh2], ['1','2'] )
```

And this:

```
lh1, = ax.plot(a, a  , 'r', marker=10 ,ms=30,markerfacecolor='none',markeredgewidth=1.5)
lh2, = ax.plot(a, 2*a, 'y', marker=11 ,ms=30,markerfacecolor='none',markeredgewidth=1.5)
lh3, = ax.plot(a, 3*a, 'o', marker='D',ms=30,markerfacecolor='none',markeredgewidth=1.5)
```

But the result is not good, and I'd like to avoid this type of hacking.
[image]

[image]

Comment: It's definitely possible to create double markers directly as well as to create a hexagram marker. However before looking deeper into this, did you consider just calling the function twice, once with the upper triangle, once with the lower?

Comment: I think you would want to use the markers `10`  and `11`, and `"D"` for the up, down and combined case respectively?